# Square of a number using Duplex Method

Tags: number-theory

For example, calculating square of $654$ using Duplex Method as given below 
(reference: [Speed Maths Square Calculator](http://www.careerbless.com/calculators/speedmaths/square/index.php))
Is duplex method a reliable method to calculate square and can this be proven mathematically? Where can I find all such methods and is there any special area of mathematics which focus on speedy calculations? I am interested in this because if such methods are available, studying them will give an upper edge for my exams.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works for squares of three digit numbers of the form $(100a+10b+c)^2$

Multiplying out and then grouping by powers of $10$ gives $10000\times a^2+ 1000 \times 2ab +100 \times (2ac+b^2) +10 \times 2bc + 1 \times c^2$

A more naturally symmetric form might be
$10000\times a^2+ 1000 \times (ab+ba) +100 \times (ac+b^2+ca) +10 \times (bc +cb)+ 1 \times c^2$

There are natural extensions for squares of more digits

Whether this is a speed improvement on other methods or just using a calculator are different issues

Answer (score 1):

Here is a competitive method for the case at hand, that might inspire you for other calculations.

$$\tag{1}654^2=\underbrace{(650+4)^2}_{(a+b)^2}=\underbrace{650^2+8 \times 650+4^2}_{a^2 + 2 a b + b^2}=65^2 \times 100 + 8 \times 650 + 4^2$$

Among the 3 terms above, the last 2 can be easily computed.

The computation of $65^2$ is also easy, knowing the following rule for squaring numbers terminated by 5:

$$\tag{2}(\overline{N5})^2=\overline{(N\times(N+1))25}$$

(examples: $25^2=\overline{(2\times3)25}=625), \ 35^2=\overline{(3\times4)25}=1225$...)

Conclusion: (1) gives $\underbrace{\overline{4225} \times 100}_{422500} \ + \  + \ 5200 \ + \ 16 = 427716.$

Exercice: prove (2).